# ClassNotFoundException for Apache Derby database

Tags: jakarta-ee, classpath, derby, sqlexception

I am trying to use Apache Derby in Network mode for my J2EE Web App using Eclipse
I am getting the following error:

```
ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
SQLException: SQLState: 08001
```

I have already added the `derbyclient.jar` and `derby.jar` in classpath variable of system and the project. I cannot figure out the problem

Comment: Have you tried to do Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver"); manually to check if client library is really in classpath?

Comment: Just tried your idea. It is working when I created a different class and ran it as java application. But it is giving exception in the JSP scriptlet.

Comment: What application server/container do you use?

Comment: I am using Apache tomcat 6 server for J2EE 6 project

Comment: Check that Derby client jar is in the WEb-INF/lib folder of your app or in lib folder of Tomcat

Comment: The jars were not in lib folder. I copied all those jars in folder and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can and should post your solution as an answer to this question(which you can accept later).

Answer (score 0):

You must add `derbyclient.jar` to `YourProject\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib`. Not needed to add `derby.jar` to classpath.

It's helped me.